# LibGDX HealthBar: How can i improve it

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have been making a simple game using LibGDX and now I am trying to add a health bar in my game.
I have successfully added the health bar in the game and it is working fine at this moment.

The problem , however, is how to further modify this code like professionals do.
I am still in learning process so I have been trying to figure how to further make it look
better, succinct, and professional but wan't able to furnish it further.

I have pasted my HealthBar class code below. I will appreciate any suggestion so that I can think better and efficient when writing any codes in future.

```
public class HealthBar extends Actor{

protected float MaxHealthX;
protected static float HealthBarY= 36;
float decreaseRate = 0;
float addHealth = 0;
float deductHealth = 0;
ShapeRenderer sr;
static private boolean projectionMatrixSet;
private boolean isHitE = false;
private boolean isHitI = false;
float totalSubractedHP = 0;
float totalAddedHP = 0;

public HealthBar(){

    sr = new ShapeRenderer();
    projectionMatrixSet = false;

}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha){

    //if a main character is hit by enemy
    if(isHitE==true){
        //subtractHP();
        totalSubractedHP += 1;
        isHitE = false;
    }

    if(isHitI==true){
        totalAddedHP += 10;
        isHitI = false;
    }
    MaxHealthX=296-decreaseRate+totalAddedHP-totalSubractedHP;

    batch.end();
    if(!projectionMatrixSet){
        sr.setProjectionMatrix(batch.getProjectionMatrix());
    }
    sr.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
    sr.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    sr.rect(40,650,300,40);

    if(isOutOfHealth() == false){
    sr.setColor(Color.RED);
    sr.rect(42, 652, MaxHealthX, HealthBarY);
    }

    sr.end();

    batch.begin();

}

//updating health decrease rate as time passes by
public void updateHealthBar(float delta) {
    decreaseRate += 10*delta;       

}

//checks whether health is greater than zero
public boolean isOutOfHealth(){
    if(MaxHealthX > 0){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}


//checking if hit by enemy
public boolean isHitByEnemy(){
    isHitE = true;
    return isHitE;
}

public boolean isHitByItem(){
    isHitI = true;
    return isHitI;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ShapeRenderer` is normaly only used for debuging. In the endgame most times only `SpriteBatch` is used.
In the `draw` method you call `batch.end()` which calls `flush()`. This method is a bit "heavy" and should only be called, if it is really neccessary. So in your case it would be better to use `batch` instead of `ShapeRenderer` to draw the whole `HealthBar`.
Even better:
Use the `Scene2D` `Progressbar`, which should be exactly what you are looking for.
This `ProgressBar` need a `range` (for example min = 0, max = 100), a `stepSize` (for example 1.0) a `boolean vertical`, and a `ProgressBarStyle`.
The `ProgressBarStyle` in your case just needs 2 `Drawable`s:
`backgroung`
`disabledBackground`

You can then use `setValue(maxHealthX)`, which will set the `background` from 0-`maxHealthX` (rounded to the nearest `stepSize`) and `disabledBackground` from `maxHealthX`-end of progressbar.

Comment: Hello Springrbua thanks for providing a better solution. :) I will take your advice and further furnish it. Thank you!!

Comment: @denden130 i'm glad i could help! Please tell me if it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do it ,implement logic your self

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.Format;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;


public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
     int i=0;
    Texture texture,texture2;
    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        initTestObjects() ;
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();


        batch.draw(texture2,100,100,300,20);
    batch.draw(texture,100,100,i,20);
    if(i>300)
    {
        i=0;
    }
    i++;

        batch.end();
    }
    private void initTestObjects() {

        int width =1 ;
        int height = 1;
        Pixmap pixmap = createProceduralPixmap(width, height,0,1,0);
        Pixmap pixmap2 = createProceduralPixmap(width, height,1,0,0);

    texture = new Texture(pixmap);
    texture2 = new Texture(pixmap2);



        }



    private Pixmap createProceduralPixmap (int width, int height,int r,int g,int b) {
        Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(width, height, Format.RGBA8888);

        pixmap.setColor(r, g, b, 1);
        pixmap.fill();

        return pixmap;
        }
}
```